# Next post in category

Tags: theme-development, themes, next-post-link

i tried to make my previous/next to move only for one category,but i can't seen to make it work... http://pastebin.com/kDECBeKE this is a pastebin of my template-tags.php where i have my next_post_link code.
Here's a short version of the code :

```
 <?php previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'sixteen' ) . '</span> %title' ); ?>
            <?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'sixteen' ) . '</span>' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just use the default [get_next_post_link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_next_post_link/) with $in_same_term set to true. Have you tried that?

---

Instead of your

```
<?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'sixteen' ) . '</span>' ); ?>
```

try this

```
<?php next_post_link ( '%link &rarr;', '%title', true, '', 'category' ); ?>
```

Comment: I read about that on google,sadly i'm a noob in coding so i can only do basic stuff,i don't know how to set it to true because i can't really find $in_same_term,should i add it in the code ? If so,where exactly ? Thanks

Comment: Check the edit.